# Kafka consumer console subscribing to multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I use Ubuntu server 16.04 to try using Kafka. For the command to start a producer and a consumer console I use the following.

producer console :

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic hello-topic
```

consumer console :

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --from-beginning --topic hello-topic
```

but the command above only subscribes to one topic. How can I subscribe to multiple topics?

Comment: Did you try the whitelist option of the console consumer?

Comment: @Harald not yet, i don't know there is whitelist

Answer (score 25):

First you should connect with the option *bootstrap-server* to the Kafka server itself not the zookeeper server.

For multiple topics you use the *whitelist* option. This will get interpreted as a  regular expression and has to get quoted, see [Kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_mirror_maker).
So a correct command would be:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --whitelist 'hello-topic|world-topic|another-topic'
```

Other expressions are also possible, like

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --whitelist '.*'
```

---

**BE AWARE**

> For convenience we allow the use of ',' instead of '|' to specify a list of topics.

Does not work with Kafka 2.0, perhaps only when mirroring, which I did not try yet.

Comment: i am using kafka 2.6.0
this command is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Hi The actual problem lies in the syntax, from version to verison it keeps on changing.

./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic muleesb

would work for you

**Reason**

For kafka versions above kafka_2.11-2.1.0: ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server IP:PORT --from-beginning --topic TOPIC

For Kafka versions kafka_2.11_0.9.0.0 and below: /kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper IP:PORT —-topic TOPIC --from-beginning --whitelist TOPIC

[Exactly one of whitelist/blacklist/topic is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803119/exactly-one-of-whitelist-blacklist-topic-is-required/44364892)

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by Harald, use whitelist / blacklist option to include / exclude a set of topics for consumption.

```
sh kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --from-beginning --whitelist Hello,World
```

Comment: This is not working for me when I use `--bootstrap-server kafkaserver:9092`. Since the old consumer will be deprecated, is there a way for new consumers to dot that?

Comment: @colin-SBI which Kafka version are you using ?

Comment: kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1