# Exactly one of whitelist/blacklist/topic is required

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to start Kafka consumer but it is showing below error:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 —topic Hello-Kafka 
Exactly one of whitelist/blacklist/topic is required.
Option                                  Description                            
------                                  -----------                            
--blacklist <blacklist>                 Blacklist of topics to exclude from    
                                          consumption.                         
--bootstrap-server <server to connect                                          
  to>                                                                          
--consumer.config <config file>         Consumer config properties file.       
--csv-reporter-enabled                  If set, the CSV metrics reporter will  
                                          be enabled                           
--delete-consumer-offsets               If specified, the consumer path in     
                                          zookeeper is deleted when starting up

............
............
```

Comment: I guess it's `--topic Hello-Kafka` (with two dashed, not just one)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You can use as below:**

bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic Hello-Kafka

Answer (score 4):

Adding `--whitelist Hello-Kafka`
helped me.

Answer (score 1):

bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning

Answer (score 0):

bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 —topic Hello-Kafka --from-beginning --whitelist Hello-Kafka

Answer (score 0):

For kafka versions above kafka_2.11-2.1.0: ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server IP:PORT --from-beginning --topic TOPIC

For Kafka versions kafka_2.11_0.9.0.0 and below: /kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper IP:PORT —-topic TOPIC --from-beginning --whitelist TOPIC